# Login Authentication isn't acknowledging an existing OpenID

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

This comes with a discussion with user [Robusto](https://stackexchange.com/users/100982/robusto) that initially started from an inability to register a new account for the [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange Blog](http://english.blogoverflow.com).

When trying to register for an account, the OpenID is not recognized, as shown in the following image:

[image: Image of login with the message "This login is new to Stack Exchange"]

However, the login being presented is not a new login, and is the same login used for his English Language & Usage Stack Exchange account. This has been confirmed to happen even with a clean cache and no potential confusion by the system that he is logging in with a different credential.

While this is consistent for the blog entry, Robusto had also noted that this occurs occasionally when trying to log into chat from a new device, or when logging into an account on a site he hasn't visited in a long time. This leads me to believe that there's something deeper at issue here than just the blog, but something else about his OpenID not being recognized.

If anyone else has been experiencing issues where your login credentials are not being recognized as existing on the Stack Exchange Network, when indeed they do, please speak up and provide any extra detail that you might have.

Comment: I have had issues that were probably similar, although I don't remember the details. I remember I once had to create a new a new account because I couldn't log in after clearing out cookies/cache. I also remember being unable to log in when I was in France, on wifi on my brother's laptop. I use MyOpenID for my normal account.

Comment: What you write doesn't quite fit to my experience but maybe it's the same cause. There seems to be a recent change that causes the openID login to fail when adblock is enabled. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156948/login-process-incompatible-with-adblock-plus if this is the case for more details.

Comment: @s.Daniel: Nope, not using Adblock.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the user @GraceNote is writing about.

I'm still having this problem. I'm trying to write a blog article for http://english.blogoverflow.com/ and the error still happens. I go to http://english.blogoverflow.com/wp-admin/ from an SE site that I'm already logged in on, and it insists I authenticate, which I try to do through Google. It says this account is unknown. But if I go to a fresh browser, clear cache, cookies, etc., and login with that same Google account, I log in to SE just fine ... except for the blog site. Can somebody help me with this?

**Another piece of the puzzle**

If I go to my profile page on EL&U.SE and click "network profile" I see that I am no longer logged in there. When I try to log in there with my Google credentials, I get the same "This login is new to Stack Exchange" message. This has to be some kind of authentication issue between SE and Google.