# Unable to login with Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, login, firefox

I am unable to login to stackoverflow, meta.stackoverflow or askubuntu.com using Firefox 17 on Ubuntu 12.10 with Stack Exchange

It just hangs there showing the moving 3 dots: "..."

It's a clean install of the OS. 
Firefox has the following extension / plugins installed:

- Dummy Lipsum 3.0.0
- Firebug 1.10.6
- FirePHP 0.7.1
- Global Menu integration 3.6.4 (ubuntu addon)
- Live HTTP Headers 0.17
- Web Developer 1.2.2
- Adblock Plus 2.2.1

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

It seems that Adblock Plus it's the culprit. Disabling makes it work!

Comment: Same problem here. Thanks for the update that it's Adblock.

Comment: Here are some workarounds: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156948/login-process-incompatible-with-adblock-plus