# Can't log in via Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Login process incompatible with Adblock Plus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156948/login-process-incompatible-with-adblock-plus)

When I go to log in and choose "Login with Stack Exchange", I get the loading GIF image, but it never makes it through to the next page (or the content isn't loaded, or whatever. I can't remember how it's laid out).

Login with Facebook works fine.

It appears to be an issue with the iframe that loads the login box, as I can get to the login box just fine when I request the same `src` from the iframe in a separate browser window.

**Details:**

- Browser: Chrome v23
- Works correctly in other browsers.
- Clearing cache doesn't help
- If I manually enter the [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) and log in, then log back out, then try to log in again, it works, because it doesn't need to prompt me for credentials the second time. I assume this means that the authentication information is stored in session, which scares me a little.

Comment: Try to disable all the Chrome extensions you installed, good chance one of them is causing this problem.

Comment: What does http://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help give you? (And see also "What else do I need" in [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need))

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you use [Adblock Plus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock_Plus). If this is the case, see *[Login process incompatible with Adblock Plus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156948/login-process-incompatible-with-adblock-plus)* for more details.

Comment: Man, you "saved" me today! Thank you very much. I'm having Adblock at my Firefox and Google Chrome and I could not login untill I've disabled it! After successfull login I've put it back and now I'm happy!