# Unable to enter login credentials in Chrome on Windows

Tags: support, google-chrome, login, windows-7

I basically am a Linux user, but I have one Windows machine.

In this machine I am unable to login to SO in Chrome.

I get this, and can wait forever:

[image: StackOverflow login problem]

This happens only on Chrome + Windows,
I have no problems with IE, Firefox (Ubuntu & Windows) or Chrome & Chromium on Ubuntu.

I tried to refresh without cache (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>), without luck.

Anyone encountered this?

Comment: Did you try completely clearing your cache? I can't reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: In what version of Chrome is this happening?

Comment: I am also experiencing this on Chrome Version 23.0.1271.95 on Windows 7 32 bit.  This only started occurring for me this week (I first noticed on Tuesday). EDITED TO ADD: if I clear cache and delete cookies I get the same result.  Also, I am attempting to use the "log in with StackExchange" method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Login process incompatible with AdBlock Plus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156948/login-process-incompatible-with-adblock-plus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Chrome Developer Tools I determined the problem is related to a request to openid.stackexchange.com/affiliate - this request fails.

Edited to add: As [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150235/tim-stone) pointed out, this is a [known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156948/login-process-incompatible-with-adblock-plus) related to the AdBlock plugin.

The linked thread provides a solution which I can verify works:

> For Chrome, add this filter:
>
> @@openid.stackexchange.com/affiliate/*

Comment: Are you [using AdBlock Plus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156948/login-process-incompatible-with-adblock-plus)?

Comment: Funny you mention that I was JUST reading that post after doing some googling on the openid.stackexchange.com/affiliate string.  I am indeed using that extension, and I note in that linked thread that this seems to be a known issue and is not supported.  I think since the post you linked has a much better explanation/more detail than this thread, this one should be closed as a dupe.

Comment: Disabling AdBlock Plus solved the issue. Thanks.