# Stack Overflow login problem from two different networks

Tags: support, stack-overflow, login, authentication

I am quite a new user and recently started to access Stack Overflow both from the office and from home. I created an account and a password and also added a few OpenID logins to my account (Yahoo, Google, and Facebook) when I was in the office.

The problem is that I can log in to Stack Overflow from home **if I only first use [AppGate](http://www.cryptzone.com/products/appgate/security-server/)** to connect to my office network. So, both from the office and from home (the latter through AppGate), I have no problem to be properly identified when opening the URL. But there is no authentication done from home, when I'm not using AppGate.

I also tried to log off from the office connection and log in on my home connection, but after whatever type of authentication I tried, I still was not able to see my personal profile section instead of "Log in". The only way to authenticate is to originate my browsing from the office network.

I cleared the browsing data in Chrome and also tried it in Internet Explorer, but it made no difference.

**[UPDATE]**

I found a possible workaround, but I don't know if it's not only a temporary one. By executing the following command in `FireBug`'s console the problem seems to be fixed:

```
localStorage.clear()
```

**[UPDATE 2]**

While the above workaround actually had no effect, **the solution for the issue was to change some content filtering settings on my router** (already logged in for more than 48 hours).

Comment: What does http://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help give you? (And see also "What else do I need" in [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need).)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Arjan and @s-Daniel, I'll be able to test it in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Moste likely you use adblock. See [Login process incompatible with Adblock Plus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156948/login-process-incompatible-with-adblock-plus) if this is the case for more details.