# Why can't I login to any Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, login, stack-exchange-openid

This evening I had cause to log in to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), a site I hadn't visited before, and I found myself unable to login.

After clicking on `log in with Stack Exchange` I wait and wait and the username and password boxes never appear.

[image]

Thinking it was my browser, I cleared out my cache, and tried again, with the same result. The browser itself is Chrome 23.0.1271.95 m, on Windows 8, which claims to be up to date.

I then visited a few other SE sites. On sites I've logged in to before, I was logged back in automatically, click here to refresh the page. On sites I haven't logged in to before, such as [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/), I got the same result as Cross Validated.

At that point I did a global logout and then cleared any remaining cookies I could find. When I went back to attempt to log in again, I could no longer log in to *any* Stack Exchange site.

On the computer which is failing to log in, I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> and looked at the Network tab. When I click `log in with Stack Exchange` a number of requests fly by; the last one being `POST /users/login/global`, which returns a 404 Not Found.

I also see the following additional error in the console:

```
Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect
```

I suspect these may be related to my problem.

(I am posting this from a different browser from which I was already logged in; I'm quite afraid to attempt logging out... And I'm just a sysadmin, not that much of a developer anymore, so if I forgot anything important, please let me know.)

Comment: I was getting "Welcome AMAR..." banner(on top of page) too but it remained not logged in. Was logged in at other domains i.e. [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) etc. Finally cleared cookies only for [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) and opened it again. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem, and I got the same messages as you did in the debugging console.

If you look at the source code for the file that generates that warning, you can see that the file implements functionality for extensions (comment at the top).

The only extension I have is Adblock. I disabled that for a minute and I was able to log in.

Comment: Hmm.  Given that, see also: [Login process incompatible with AdBlock Plus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156948/135887)

Comment: Bingo. I'm logged in after disabling Adblock Plus.