# Just earned a hat. Went to collect, and authentication won't recognize me. Bah, humbug!

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2012

Talk about giving with one hand and taking away with the other.

See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156400/144195) for an explanation of the issue in detail. I thought it was only for the blog site, but apparently it involves hats, too.

Seriously, this is getting tiresome. I'm close to 100K rep among the various SE sites I belong to, and I think I've earned the right for my login to be known by now, and not to be told

[image: Image of login with the message "This login is new to Stack Exchange"]

Are there any devs reading this who can help? Or am I being "handed my hat" in another sense?

Comment: +1: had the same issue.

Comment: I pinged a developer about this. Hopefully this should be resolved soon!

Comment: There's a hat for that.

Comment: Same problem here...just logged in anyway and that seems to work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Geoff D. cleared sessions on server side and I am good to go. Thanks, Geoff, you rock!

Comment: Woo! GO DALGAS.

Comment: Also, @Robusto, welcome to Winter Bash! Have fun collecting hats~!

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Me happy camper now.